# Need help resolving Clover issue

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, ant, clover

Forgive me if the question is too vague. I am not a clover expert but i need this issue resolved. Clover seem to be having issues with a particular class as show in the trace below. I need to exclude this class entirely from the clovers part cause the class isnt all that necessary. Is this even a clover issue or just a java issue? thanks again and sorry if this just trivial.

```
enter code here   [javac] [apt] warning: Annotation types without processors:  [java.lang.SuppressWarnings]
  [apt] 1 warning
   [apt] Ignoring compiler attribute for the APT task, as it is fixed
[javac] Compiling 268 source files to  /home/retail_website/build/.src/Platform/AlibrisBiz/build/classes
[clover] Clover Version 2.6.0, built on September 09 2009 (build-771)
[clover] Loaded from: /home/retail_website/build/clover/clover.jar
[clover] Clover: Commercial License registered to Alibris.
[clover] Updating existing database at '/home/retail_website/build/clover.database/clover.db'.
[clover] Processing files at 1.5 source level.
[clover] Clover all over. Instrumented 268 files (27 packages).
[clover] Elapsed time = 7.155 secs. (37.456 files/sec, 9,859.259 /tmp/clover51982.tmp/com/maxmind/geoip/regionName.java:4: code too large for try statement
[javac] static public String regionNameByCode(String country_code,String region_code) {try{__CLR2_6_09so9sogbuuz0jf.R.inc(12696);
[javac]                                                                                   ^
[javac] /tmp/clover51982.tmp/com/maxmind/geoip/regionName.java:4: code too large
[javac] static public String regionNameByCode(String country_code,String region_code) {try{__CLR2_6_09so9sogbuuz0jf.R.inc(12696);
[javac]                      ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 2 errors
```

Comment: can somebody say something ...anything

Comment: Most likely java issue. Java limits a single method of bytecode can be max 64Kb. Else you get the "code too large" error. How big is this regionNameByCode method?

Comment: thanks for the response. Its quite huge ...thus the problem. Is there a way to filter (like ant) out a specific class out of clover instrumentation? that way we wont deal with this class at all. If so, in which clover file can this be done in. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can exclude classes on package level from the ant tasks.

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/6.+Ant+Task+Reference

Example

```
<clover-setup enabled="${enable}">
     <files>
       <exclude name="**/cenqua/clover/**/*.java"/>
     </files>
</clover-setup>
```

See more at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup

If you're running using Maven, then follow this http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover-for-Maven+2+User%27s+Guide#Clover-for-Maven2User%27sGuide-ControllingwhichSourceFilesareInstrumented

Answer (score 0):

Java limits the method bytecode size to 64kb as explained by other contributor. 
One solution is to exclude the file as mentioned by some one. 
Another solution is to change the instrumentation level to "method". By default it is set to statements. Following change has to be incorporated in clover-setup tag.

**clover-setup instrumentationLevel="method"**